# Combo Box inside the DataGridView of WinForm application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox, datagridviewcolumn

Using `ComboBox` in `DataGridView` :

**Implementation** :

`DataGridView` is binding with the datatable, when use click over any row, than this row cell element convert into `ComboBox` and now user able to select `ComboBox` elements .

**Issue** :

It is working fine for all the cases,
 `dgvTables(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) = l_cmbTableList` 
but issue is coming when `e.ColumnIndex` and `e.RowIndex` having same value, at that time `ComboBox` list item looks jumpy, user not able to select this `ComboBox` items
at first time.

**Code** :

1.

```
Private Sub dgvTables_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvTables.CellClick

If e.ColumnIndex > -1 Then
  If dgvTables.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name.Contains("TableCaption") Then
   dgvTables(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) = l_cmbTableList ' Problem is coming at that point,       dropdown list is jumpy, user not able to select item .
   l_cmbTableList.DisplayMember = CONST_TableCaption
   l_cmbTableList.ValueMember = CONST_TableCaption
   l_cmbTableList.DataSource = dt
   l_cmbTableList.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing

End If
```

2.

```
Private Sub dgvTables_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgvTables.EditingControlShowing
'Set the value of the object
  cmbEditingComobTables = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
  If Not cmbEditingComobTables Is Nothing Then
  AddHandler cmbEditingComobTables.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf       editingCombo_SelectedIndexChanged
  cmbEditingComobTables.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
  AddHandler cmbEditingComobTables.DrawItem, AddressOf cmb_DrawItem ' This attached event  will fire and set the color of combo box item
End If
```

3.

```
Private Sub cmb_DrawItem(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs)
  If Not e.Index = -1 Then
  Dim cmb As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
  Dim dr As DataRowView = DirectCast(cmb.Items(e.Index), DataRowView)
  e.DrawBackground()
  e.Graphics.DrawString(dr(cmb.DisplayMember).ToString(), e.Font, New  SolidBrush(Color.Gray), e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
End If
```

Comment: You need to edit the data gridview template and give combo box a label which u can refer to in your code. Is your combo box refreshing page when clicked?

Comment: Thanks for your your reply, but issue is that, when I select the cell of datagridview, than I just add DataGridViewComboBoxCell object in  dgvTables(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) = l_cmbTableList,  Now Problem is coming when I am selecting dropdown value. not able to select item from dropdown list at first time. list get jump.